# Image height wont scale down

Tags: html, css

Is there no way for an image to automatically scale down in size based on the container height? I have set a height and my nested img tag will not scale down. It keeps overflowing my `.modal-wrapper .modal` div. Right now I have `overflow:hidden` set to prevent the image from displaying. I need the image to scale and stay within the div.

I have tried the following:

```
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0rq9newh/

Comment: Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) and [why an image of your code is not acceptable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Both of those guidelines also apply to all other external resources such as fiddles. Questions containing code must **always** include the code directly in the question itself as a [repro].

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
img{
  object-fit: contain;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: play with the object-fit properties. I think what you want is fill.

Comment: `object-fit` has not influence if you set a static width and height. Then it will always have the height and width. `height: 100%` only works on parents with defined instead of calculated height (height: auto).

Comment: @tacoshy you're right. What I make of the question is that he/she wants the modal div of specific static height and the image to fully cover it.